# Jsp tag confusions

Tags: jsp

i am new to jsp, I am currently studying an example i got from online. some tags confused me.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> 
<html>
<head>
    <link href="<s:url value="/resources/main.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <title><s:text name="label.employees"/></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="titleDiv"><s:text name="application.title"/></div>  
<h1><s:text name="label.employees"/></h1>
```

1. in line 6, what is label here mean? does label.employees here define a new variable?
2. in line 9, what is titleDiv and application.title? define new variables?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That's not "just" JSP. That's Struts.

Answer (score 2):

On lines 6 and 9, the "label.employees" and "application.title" strings are parameters being passed to the Struts `text` tag.  This is not defining a new variable, rather it is telling the Struts tag which already-defined variable it should consult in order to find the text that it is supposed to show.

As for "titleDiv", that is just a standard CSS class name.  It has nothing to do with JSP or JSP tags.  It works the same in a JSP page as it does in any standard HTML page.

You may find the [reference documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/text.html) helpful.

Comment: i realized there is another properties file. I am not sure why do they store as *.* format? any particular reason? I don't see anywhere in the class using resource bundle tho, in struts, do i need to explicitly define a resource bundle or do i just put those names in struts.properties?

Comment: does struts automatically search properties files?

Comment: I've not dealt with Struts myself, but the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/localization.html) states that yes, it does indeed search for `.properties` files, and that you should call your `.properties` files "package.properties".